# buffer.writeBigUInt64LE does not exist for React app Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I need access to the [buffer.writeBigUint64LE](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#bufwritebigint64levalue-offset) function, however, it appears that it does not exist in the [buffer api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer) for the browser.

Is anyone aware of any possible solutions for this or do I have to write my own buffer for `Uint8Array`?

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-mayer-e078s3?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues actually.
First, when using the buffer package, there are risks that your packager will try to package the actual node buffer package. (See this [warning](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer#usage))
To avoid this, import buffer/
Like this

```js
import { Buffer } from "buffer/";
```

Then, you have a type mismatch.
`writeBigUInt64LE` expects a BigInt, which is not a Number

You have to write it like this, to create a BigInt from your litteral:

```js
buf.writeBigUInt64LE(5n, 0);
```

[Corrected Codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-danny-rc5510)